# How to change to same image every 4 times(unity3D)

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, scripting, unityscript

I've got a 2d image. What I want to make it do is- everytime I click the sprite it would change an image(in a specific order) and repeat the image every 4 times I click it(So it loops the order every 4 times). I don't have an idea for how to do it because I'm new to unity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post what you have tried! it will help others to provide answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to infinite loop numbers in while loops? (Unity3D- unityscript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714601/how-to-infinite-loop-numbers-in-while-loops-unity3d-unityscript)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you've got an array or list of the images in the order you want them shown in (I'll call this `images`), and you've got a way of detecting a click on the sprite. There are many ways you can do what you want in code, one of them would look something like this:

```
int imageNum = 0;                               //this should be class wide
...
<sprite click detection>
{
    imageNum++;                                 //increment the imageNum
    imageNum = imageNum >= 4 ? 0 : imageNum;    //reset to 0 on the 4th click
    sprite = images[imageNum];                  //set the sprite to the next image
}
```

If you post what you've already tried I can make this code closer to what you actually want.

Comment: Your example is begging for a little golf (but OP, don't really write this or you'll hate yourself when you try to read it later): `if (sprite click detection) sprite = images[imageNum = (imageNum + 1)%4];`

Answer (score 0):

Try learning some c# or basic java tutorials before jumping into the world of unity, it will help tons. As for the question, create a script for the object or clicking an event with an basic counter that increments the value by 1 for every click. something like:

```
    while(counter = 4)
{
   picture.source = <new picture>
   counter.int = 1
}
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: Hi, there is a bug in unity when you use the while loop it confuses the engine so it doesn't responds. I've tried while loops before but it just crashes. I tried the if statement before asking the question but it would only change the image into the 3rd image straight away and I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. Its because I haven't added return; at the end of the loop. But theres one problem. When I click it the fourth time it just goes straight to the 1st picture without displaying the fourth picture. I think it happenes because when counter = 4 the counter just turns straight to number 1 without delaying the picture. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: @George Gall there are a quite a lot of problems with that code. For starters, you've used an assignment operator in the while condition. This will result in the value 4 being assigned to `counter` every iteration, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: How do you do that? @Adam H