# How to infinite loop numbers in while loops? (Unity3D- unityscript)

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, scripting, while-loop, unityscript

```
function OnMouseDown () {
    rotationNumber +=1;
}

function Update () {
    while (rotationNumber == 1) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = leftArrow;
        return;
    } 
    while (rotationNumber == 2) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = upArrow;
        return;
    }
    while (rotationNumber == 3) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = rightArrow;
        return;
    }
    while (rotationNumber == 4) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = upArrow;
        rotationNumber = 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

I want to loop this but when I click it the fourth time it just goes straight to the first image. I tried yield WaitForSeconds but it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using while loops instead of a switch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting rotationNumber to 1 inside the while loop. Do it in this way:

```
function OnMouseDown () {
    rotationNumber += 1;
    if ( rotationNumber > 4 ) rotationNumber = 1;
}

function Update () {
    while (rotationNumber == 1) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = leftArrow;
        return;
    } 
    while (rotationNumber == 2) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = upArrow;
        return;
    }
    while (rotationNumber == 3) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = rightArrow;
        return;
    }
    while (rotationNumber == 4) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = upArrow;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are using a while loop within in an update loop, but try this below.  Every time you click the rotation number increases and the sprite is changed until the rotationNumber variable **is > 4** in which case it **resets the variable back to 1**.

```
function Update()
{
    if(rotationNumber == 1)
    {
         gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = leftArrow;
    }else if(rotationNumber ==2)
    {
         gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = upArrow;  
    }else if(rotationNumber ==3)
    {
         gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = rightArrow;
    }else if(rotationNumber == 4)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = upArrow;  
    }else if(rotationNumber > 4)
    {
        rotationNumber = 1;
    }
}
```